# How to stop Power Bi measure from hiding other fields when using the filter function within Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I created a measure in Power BI using DAX that gets the total quantity for a specific item in the 'item' column. But when I use that measure in a table in Power Bi, it acts as a filter and hides other items from showing up in the table. How can I handle this? Do I need to create a measure for each item now?

Here is my DAX expression for the measure:

```
Qty 'item name'= 

Calculate
(
    Sum
    (
        table[qty]
    )
    ,
    FILTER
    (       
        table,
        table[Item]="item name"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the field list of you visual, select *Show items with no data* option in the field dropdown menu.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-show-items-no-data